# Function with param not called in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a form with serveral Dialog, one of them call a function with parameter, but I don't know why is not working. Other dialog are working perfectly. The dialog with parameters:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="windowsConfirmOperation" position="center middle" resizable="false"
header="¡Warning!" closable="false" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" 
id="idWindowsConfirmOperation" modal="true">
<p:panel>
     <div class="DispBlock Responsive100">
        <p:outputLabel value="Are you sure?" 
            escape="false"/>
     </div>
 </p:panel> 
 <div class="DispBlock ui-contenedor-botones-accion Fright"> 
     <p:commandButton value="YES"                            
         oncomplete="PF('windowsConfirmOperation').hide();"
        update="@form" process="@form"
        action="#{queryView.confirmOperation('true')}">
     </p:commandButton> 
     <p:commandButton value="NO"                            
         oncomplete="PF('windowsConfirmOperation').hide();"
        update="@form" process="@form" 
        action="#{queryView.confirmOperation('false')}">
     </p:commandButton>
 </div>
</p:dialog>
```

And my view class called QueryView:

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class QueryView {        

        ....

        public void confirmOperation(String confirm) {
        if ("true".equals(confirm)) {
            doSomeThing();
        }
    }       
}
```

I debug but the dialog never call the function. I changed parameters of Boolean to String but not working. What am I doing wrong?

Regards.

Comment: code looks fine to me... did you try clean and recompile ?

Comment: i don't see any `h:form` element ?

Comment: @Arun I clean and recompile a lots of time.

Comment: @jNick I have h:form, but I copy only the component but the tag h:form is in code.

Comment: @irieill I checked this post but the first look don't solved my problem.

Comment: Chema, could you paste entire form code and bean ?

Comment: Your problem is not in the code which you have posted. I just copy&paste it to a clean web project, and it's working fine.

Comment: @Arun Sorry but I can't copy the entire code.

Comment: @stg Then I try looking in other code place. Any  suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I modified my logic and now the code works.

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="windowsConfirmOperation" position="center middle" resizable="false"
header="¡Warning!" closable="false" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" 
id="idWindowsConfirmOperation" modal="true">
<p:panel>
     <div class="DispBlock Responsive100">
        <p:outputLabel value="Are you sure?" 
            escape="false"/>
     </div>
 </p:panel> 
 <div class="DispBlock ui-contenedor-botones-accion Fright"> 
     <p:commandButton value="YES"                            
         oncomplete="PF('windowsConfirmOperation').hide();" process="@this"
        action="#{queryView.confirmOperation}">
     </p:commandButton> 
     <p:commandButton value="NO"                            
        onclick="PF('windowsConfirmOperation').hide();"
        >
     </p:commandButton>
 </div>
</p:dialog>
```

1. I have changed the param process="@form" for **process="@this"**. I only process the button not all form.
2. How NO button only close the dialog I changed it. Now only use onclick function.
3. How only the YES button use the function, now I don't need parameters. So my function changed to:

   ```
   public void confirmOperation() {
      doSomeThing();
   }
   ```

Edit: 
If I pass a Boolean works too.

```
action="#{queryView.confirmOperation('true'}">
```

and java file

```
public void confirmOperation(Boolean something) {
   doSomeThing();
}
```

With these changes my code works fine.

Regards